# PHP Form Submit Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with a textarea.

```
The textarea has multiple words separate by a comma, see below...

<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <textarea>data1, data2, data3</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

What I need to do is to create some kind of loop where the form gets submitted multiple times...

Each time is will send a different value from the textarea.

For example:

```
Start:

1. data1 .. Submit
2. data2 .. Submit
3. data3 .. Submit

End.
```

Is there a way to do this in php or php and javascript?

Comment: It will only submit once. Use AJAX.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to submit multiple time?

The easy way to do this is to sumbit the entire textbox value and then have php spilt it up using "," as a delimiter and trim off the whitespace

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <textarea name="textboxdata">data1, data2, data3</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    $textboxarray = array_map('trim',explode(",",$POST['textboxdata']));
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
 ( 
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3 

 )
```

Comment: why not use: `$textboxarray; '=' ;{'trim'; explode(",",'ksjhfdm,asdkfjh,asdfas,df');};` instead? at least you get no errors

Comment: You bold text by using `**your text**`, however your current code simply results in a strange multidimensional array

Comment: well thats not bold in your comment?  I guess this site is broken

Comment: @StevenMartin it's not bold in his comment because he is having it displayed as raw text and not rendered markdown code. How else is he to show you without it just bolding the text? Seriously, think before you comment. Also, adding `array` to the code does not make it valid, it's still wrong. This is why you don't use w3schools to learn from.

Comment: Sorry but im not some beginner, i know how to program in many languages and I had array_map in bold and it just dissappeared, this site doesnt work. like i said before if you are right, HOW DO YOU BOLD TEXT IN A CODE BLOCK?  Becuase i have ** ** and its not working????n  But i guess everyone will go silent now, becuase there isnt a way!

Comment: @StevenMartin you don't bold text in a code block. Why would you render markdown code within PHP code? You have any idea how many times the markdown rendering will inadvertently be run if you allowed that?

Comment: Once maybe??? Escape <br> tags and replace **  with a <br> tag all in one pass.why would u have ** for any other reason??? If your not in a code block then you could use <br> to bold and if your in a code block , you can't bold.   You guys just accept too much as is... Question this shit?  Like losing a rep once if a question goes on hold even if it's after you answer it, when the owner of question could have re-edited it???

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code :

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.find('textarea').text().split(',');

    data.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        $.ajax({
            url : $this.attr('action'),
            data : item,
            type : $this.attr('method')
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. get the reference of the textarea (can also be done by id if you wish).

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML
var separated = text.splt(',');
for(var a = 0 ; a < separated.length ; a++){
    //SENDREQUEST IS A FUNCTION YoU HAVE TO BUILD.
    sendRequest(separated[a].trim());
}
```